# .htaccess file is not recognized by Apache

Tags: javascript, apache, reactjs, .htaccess

I have spent 5 days on this issue, my `.htaccess` file is not recognized by Apache. It is located in `htdocs/build` beside my `index.html`. I have activated `mod_rewrite`, `AllowOveride` has been set to `All`. The file doesn't even throw a 500 Error when I give it random text, it doesn't log. On the other hand, the exact same `httpd.conf`, `react.js` build, and `.htaccess` run perfectly on my boss' computer. If I place the `.htaccess` code (its redirect code for an SPA) into `<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/build">` it runs with no fault.

The code in my `.htaccess` file is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

I am running Windows 7, I have tested this on Apache Haus 2.4.33 now it's running on 2.4.12 (to verify if it was an issue with version 33).

```
winnt:notice] [pid 4092:tid 484] AH00424: Parent: Received restart signal -- Restarting the server.
[Tue Apr 03 13:47:25.922966 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 4092:tid 484] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Apr 03 13:47:25.922966 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4092:tid 484] AH00455: Apache/2.4.12 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.1l configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Apr 03 13:47:25.923966 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4092:tid 484] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jan 28 2015 14:29:16
[Tue Apr 03 13:47:25.923966 2018] [core:notice] [pid 4092:tid 484] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Apache\\Apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Apache/Apache24'
[Tue Apr 03 13:47:25.924966 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4092:tid 484] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 988
[Tue Apr 03 13:47:26.245998 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 988:tid 168] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Apr 03 13:47:26.797053 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 988:tid 168] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Tue Apr 03 13:47:27.798153 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5308:tid 168] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
```

Comment: So what do the Apache logs say?

Comment: it doesn't log the htaccess file at all, when I do ctrl+f5 i get "404 page3.html not found"

Comment: Not the access log, the error log. I should have been more specific

Comment: yeah the error logs stay empty when I try to run the info from the htaccess, I wrote (LogLevel warn mod_rewrite.c:trace8) into httpd.conf to verify

Comment: "`AllowOveride` has been set to `All`" - `AllowOverride` has 2 `r`s - although I guess that is just a typo in your question, otherwise the server would fail to start? But where have you set this directive? Is `AccessFileName` set?

Comment: It's just a typo the server starts up with no issues, and I have set AccessFileName I tried .htaccess ", .htaccess", "htaccess", .htaccess and nothing, I placed it in a directory which gave me an error. I have tried most things online and nothing seems to work.

Comment: the AllowOverride directive is set inside the directory htdocs/build, I had even tried setting all Allow Overrides to All to see if that was the issue and it was not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED] the htaccess file generated by `npm run build` gave it a file extension `.txt`, I removed it using the command

```
    rewrite .htaccess.txt .htaccess
```

in command prompt